# C Segmentation fault function reference

Tags: c, dictionary, cs50

The `if(ptr->is_word)` on the `sizeH(node *ptr)` function is causing a segmentation fault.

```
dictionary.c:120:13: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'node' (aka 'struct node')
dictionary.c:120:13: runtime error: load of null pointer of type '_Bool'
Segmentation fault
```

If I add an `if` condition to return a specific value before this if-condition, the code executes and I make sure the root isn't null
so I guess the problem is the `ptr` isn't passed correctly to the `sizeH` function.

```
unsigned int size(void)
{
    node *ptr = root;
    printf(ptr->is_word ? "true" : "false");
    unsigned int count = sizeH(ptr);
    printf("COUNTER IN SIZE %d\n" , count);
    return 0;
}

unsigned int sizeH(node *ptr){
    if(ptr->is_word)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < N; x++){
            return 0 + sizeH(ptr->children[x]);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you call sizeH(NULL).

Comment: Edit your code to include the ```node``` struct. Edit your code to show how ```root``` is allocated. Generally just add the code that one can compile.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]. Probably `root` is `NULL` for some reason.

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code (line 120 doesn't exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of fundamental problems with your `sizeH` function. Firstly it doesn't check that the `ptr` that is passed in is not `NULL`. This is very likely to happen as your function is recursive and you have this loop that is called for each child node.

```
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++){
        return 0 + sizeH(ptr->children[x]);

    }
```

Except that the code in the loop is wrong and it'll only ever be called for the first child, which is the second issue. Because you use `return` inside the loop, it'll only ever run once. Instead you should tally up the values returned for each child node and then return that.

Making the two changes above would leave your function looking like this.

```
unsigned int sizeH(node *ptr) {
    if(ptr==NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else if(ptr->is_word) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        unsigned int ret = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            ret += sizeH(ptr->children[x]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    // return 0; This isn't needed - the code will never reach here.
}
```

It's also worth picking one coding formatting style and sticking to it rather than using a mixture as it makes for neater code.